# How to console all ID's one at a time?

Tags: javascript, dom, console.log

```js
displayHex = () => {
  const IDcaller = document.getElementClassName("rectangleWrapper");
  setInterval(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < IDcaller; i++) {
      console.log(IDcaller.id);
    }
  }, 1000);
  displayHex();
}
```

```html
<div class="parentClass" id="rectangleWrapper">
  <div class="color" id="blue">
</div>
  #5591CE
```

Here is my sample code of HTML and js file inside a folder.
the instruction are "When the page loads, console.log the messages "Here are the rectangle IDs" and then console.log all the rectangles' IDs, one at a time."

Comment: Please update your snippet with the relevant HTML

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `console.log(IDcaller[i].id);` might be more useful

Comment: Also it is `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @JoachimSauer "how to console log all ID's one at a time." that's for my homework on online javascript course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IDcaller[i].id is likely more useful
2. speling the getElementClassName incorrectly. It is getElementsByClassName
3. You want the children of the wrapper so you really want document.querySelectorAll

perhaps this

```js
displayHex = () => {
  const IDs = [...document.querySelectorAll("#rectangleWrapper .color")]
    .map(caller => caller.id); // get the IDs
  let cnt = 0;
  let tId = setInterval(() => { // save the interval variable
    if (cnt < IDs.length) {
      console.log(IDs[cnt]);
      cnt++;
    }
    else  clearInterval(tId); // stop the interval  
  }, 1000);
};
displayHex()
```

```css
#blue { background-color: #5591CE; }
#red { background-color: #FF91CE; }
#green { background-color: #11FF11; }
```

```html
<div id="rectangleWrapper">
  <div id="blue" class="color">Blue</div>
  <div id="red" class="color">Red</div>
  <div id="green" class="color">Green</div>
</div>
```